# Error in dataframe in R when trying to recode a variable

Tags: r, recode

I am workign with NLS data and try to recode the gender variable, where I called it female from the beginning and now I try to recode the following

```
 1 Male
 2 Female
 0 No Information
```

My code:

```
nlsy$female[ nlsy$female == 1 ] <- 0
nlsy$female[ nlsy$female == 2 ] <- 1
```

However, I get the following error from R:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "female", value = numeric(0)) :    replacement has 0 rows, data has 7120
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show a small example using `dput`.  According to the data you showed, the syntax should work

Comment: Did the solution wind up being that the value was 'Female' (capital 'F') and you were trying to access 'female' (lower case 'f')?  That seems to be what your comment on the answer implies.

Answer (score 1):

what I would check:

1. data.frame nlsy is not empty, by empty i mean with 0 rows / records.
2. do you have a column named 'female' in the data.frame nlsy
3. class of the column, is it integer or character or others
4. after all the checks

   nlsy$female[which(nlsy$female == 2)] <- 1

Comment: Switching from SAS to R I sometimes forget that R is case sensitive. Thanks a lot!